# Colour Code Cells in a Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a Jupyter Notebook to generate a report. I know that there are some parts of the report that are going to be more technical than what most people who are reading the report are going to care to read, but that other readers will want to dig into.
Is there a way that I can colour code groups of cells (code and markdown) in a notebook to signify to readers which parts are "optional?"

Answer (score 1):

**For Markdown**

Raw HTML tag wrappers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746874/4098013

**For Code**

I don't think there is something that would color code cells. My suggestion would be to go for hiding the more technical cells. This can hide/display cells based on button clicks - implementation [here](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/)