# Jupyter notebook stopped interpreting css in cells

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I want to change the color of one word in a cell. My code is in markdown mode:

```
<p>Hi, <span style="color: red"> my <span> friend</p>
```

But the color doesn't change. Why? :(

My notepad options:

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.4.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.26.0
ipykernel        : 6.2.0
jupyter client   : 7.0.1
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Comment: Isn't this answers your question , https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746874/16497617

Comment: incorrect answer. my problem is that these ways don't work