# How to change a text color of a code cell in Markdown?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I need to change a text color of a code cell (namely code cell, not just a text block) that is defined using "`" symbols in Markdown. All my attempts have failed and the color stays the same, which is by default black

I have tried to use `<font color="...">...<\font>` attribute and also `<span style="color:...;">...<\span>` attribute. All of them didn't work and the text is still the same as on the attached image. How can I solve this problem and finally change the color to whatever I want?
[Code cell which text I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB7lT.png)

Comment: check out this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746350/how-to-change-color-in-markdown-cells-ipython-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @Your_Card_was_Declined the answer in the post you provided works perfectly for text blocks, but I need to change the color of the text in the code cell (see the first sentence of my question); the solution in the post does not work in my case, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add syntax highlighting to a programming language, it can be written like this:

````
# For example, you want to use Python

```python
print("the syntax is highlighted")
```
````

The result would be like this:

```py
print("the syntax is highlighted")
```

### EDIT:

As far as I know, Markdown doesn't support color. So what you'll need is wrap the code cell as HTML.

Instead of this:

```
`some beautiful text here`
```

You would want to write this:

```html
<code>some beautiful text here</code>
```

And then add the span tag to change the color:

```html
<code>some <span style='color:blue'>beautiful</span> text here</code>
```

At this point, the word 'beautiful' will change to blue.

It works on my VSCode Markdown viewer. But different app will render Markdown differently.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you might misunderstood my question. I need to change the color of text in  a code cell, but your solution doesn't provide anything related to color changing

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I'd already made an edit on the answer. Hope that's what you mean and hope it could help you

Comment: you are genius! Best answer that totally helped me. Sorry for the very late response, by the way

Answer (score 0):

I tried the span without closing tags and it worked. Are you running on jupyter notebook locally?

```
<span style="color: red;">testing 

<span style="color: blue;">testing
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMY1H.jpg)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm talking about code cell and not a text block. If you turn "testing" in code cell (I wrote that in the first sentence of my question) and apply <span>, there won't be any changes

Comment: @olesatthewheel sorry, I hadn't understood that. I think it's not possible to change the color of a code cell on vanilla jupyter, maybe you could try to search for a plugin for specific code highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

for change text color of a code cell:

`<span style="color: green">Hello</span>`

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code you provided works only for text blocks. If I write <span style="color: green">`Hello`</span> and "Hello" becomes a code cell, the color of the text in the cell will be still be black