# How can I customize my README.md for GITHUB?

Tags: github, readme

I am looking for some tricks to customize my README.md in GITHUB.

I am not talking about big title, something bold or italic, but I am talking to put some shapes, flash words or some colors.
I just want to create a funny README.md in order to attract the eyes on important things.

There is a way to do that ? Thank you for your help

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that (unless you want to use images, including animated GIFs).

Comment: So, I'll search another way. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file

Comment: It's working only for visual studio previewer, but not in GitHub repository. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -2):

You need to follow a certain syntax pattern to get the correct Markdown script as your desired output.
[image]