# Based on what does GitHub decide how and where to apply colors within the README.md file?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I've been trying to figure this out by observing various README files on public repositories.

If seen stuff like encapsulating a function with ```` ```cs ```` on top and ```` ``` ```` on bottom.

Then in some places I've seen `bash` or `diff` instead of `cs`.

But I haven't been able to apply any of these options in my own README file and get them to produce the same colors.

Does it possibly have anything to do with the `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Comment: [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) is obviously unrelated.

Comment: @Flimzy: Sure - https://github.com/github/linguist#application-usage (that's where I also looked for a clue, though according to your second comment, it clearly has nothing to do with my issue).

Comment: That's just syntax highlighting for a codeblock. Look at [the source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/master/README.md) to see how it's done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add color to Github's README.md file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file)

Comment: @Flimzy: Yes, that's exactly what I did (where'd you think I got the `bash` from?). But how on earth does GitHub know how to apply colors here?

Comment: Are you asking how syntax highlighting works, or how GitHub converts markdown to HTML?

Comment: @Flimzy: No, I'm just asking what to do in my README file so that GitHub will color function and variable names in a nice manner.

Comment: You just indicated you already know the answer to that.

Comment: @Flimzy: I don't. I said it didn't work for me. And the answer you've linked - that's where I got the `diff` from - that also didn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a JavaScript snippet you can highlight the content via:

````
```javascript
content
```
````

(Read more here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks)

---

The `.gitattributes` file is not needed for the `README.md`. It is needed when GitHub ([Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist)) highlights a whole file in a wrong syntax

---

Last but not least, syntax highlighting in GitHub is made possible by the GitHub project [`linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist).

Comment: "GitHub project linguist" - is that the same one I just looked at (provided as an example in response to one of the comments to my question)?

Comment: Yes it is, GitHub linguist is the algorithm working behind syntax highlighting on GitHub. And Yes you post a programming language behind the three `. A list of all possible languages is here: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml

Comment: Oh and btw `bash` is for console commands (Linux) and `diff` is for GitHub diffs (which is also kinda an own language)

Comment: Is there a way to use this per word (or some part of the line)? Or is it applicable only an entire line (or block of lines)?

Comment: AFAIK this is only possible in code blocks. A little sneaky trick tho is, that you can make a screenshot of your desired look and embed that screenshot as a little image in your `README`. But you should only do this if it's really necessary.