# text color in Jupyter Notebook Markdown not showing in GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, markdown

In my Jupyter Notebook, I have a Markdown cell like this:

`### <font color='#fa8072'> Title 1 </font>`

This works fine in Jupyter Notebook, but after I uploaded this file to GitHub, this cell just not showing at all.

Is there a way to fix this? Or, is there a GitHub-approved way to custom text color? (this file is a text-heavy report, so I hope to add some color for titles and subtitles.)

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add color to Github's README.md file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these methods to show the Markdown text, but it will display in black on GitHub.

```html
<span style='color:green'>TEST</span>
    
<h1 style='color:green'>TEST</h1>
```

The green color will only display when you open the file in a Jupyter Notebook. Please share if you find a better solution.