# How to color a header in markdown in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I know there is a way to color fonts by using HTML tag in this way: <span style='color:green'>TEST</span>

But when I do something like <span style='color:green'>## TEST</span>, the headers feature will not appear, i.e. the font size is not enlarged.

Is there a neat way to color headers in markdown in Jupyter Notebook without using lengthy css stuff? Thanks.

I have tried searched a lot on Google and Stackoverflow but I still cannot find a solution to my problem. I am expecting a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using KATEX? You can use the '\color{name}' like showed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613687/9780713)

Comment: @F4NT0 Yea, I tried LaTex(which shall be more or less the same with KaTex I guess). I just don't know adding a hashtag sign in front of the LaTex code will work. Thanks for the post though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On github and gitlab you can use KATEX who can help with good codes like `\color{colorname}` who change the color from the text inside the `$$$$` code, like below:

```
# $${\color{purple} \boxed{ \frak{ \color{orange}Rise \space \color{cyan}and \space \color{magenta}Rise \space \color{lime}again \space \color{violet}until \space \color{lightgray}Lambs \space \color{teal}become \space \color{red}Lions !} } }$$
```

On github profile:

[image: github profile]

Like jupiter use almost the same markdown, you can check if you can use LATEX or KATEX code.

More info about LATEX on jupyter here: [towards data science - markdown latex on jupyter](https://towardsdatascience.com/write-markdown-latex-in-the-jupyter-notebook-10985edb91fd?gi=4e53b333e877)

Comment: Oh I see. So we basically just add a hashtag sign in front of the LaTex code?

Comment: yes, and it transform into a tittle