# some problems with markdown in Databricks notebook

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory, databricks, azure-databricks

I was trying to markdown some points and tried to highlight some important parts within documentation based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/grabngoinfo/databricks-notebook-markdown-cheat-sheet-1833d5ff753d) unsuccessfully.

I could manage to run the following correctly neither in the *Databricks* notebook nor *GoogleColab* notebook:

```markdown
%md

This is <span style="background-color: #FFFF00">highlighted</span>
This is <span style="color:red">red</span>
```

desired markdown results:

[image: img]

Comment: I am also seeing same issue with databricks notebooks

Comment: So far credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593416/10452700),  I could manage to change the color by `</font>` instead of  `</span>`  e.g.,  `This is <font color='red'> red </font>.` but still I can't change the text background color. I checked some [workaround1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465557/how-to-apply-color-on-text-in-markdown), [workaround1](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1440). [workaround3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509830/how-to-add-color-to-githubs-readme-md-file).

Comment: `This is <font color='red'> red </font>` does not work for me. I do not think this is supported in Databricks, but I cannot find any official documentation stating it.

Comment: @DavidGibson it works in *GoogleColab* notebook but not in *Databricks* notebook

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below in google Collab:

```
This is <font  color='red'> red </font>

<mark  style="background-color: lightblue">Rithwik</mark>
```

[image]

AFAIK, I couldn't find any Official Documentation on Markdown (Highlighting words) and this feature is not supported in Databricks by my understanding and i would suggest you raise a feature request.